# jquery 2.1.1 sortable example not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I can't get jquery sortable to work using jquery 2.1.1 and jquery ui 1.10.4. I have been using the example on http://jqueryui.com/sortable/ but I can't get it to work either. Here is my super simple test case:

```
    <ul id="sortable">
        <li id="A" class="ui-state-default">A</li>
        <li id="B" class="ui-state-default">B</li>
    </ul>

$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Calidus/F38xS/6/

I can get it to work if I use jquery 2.0.2 and jquery ui 1.10.3 but it just doesn't work using the newer versions. I really don't want to include two different versions of jquery. thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

The `jQuery UI` you have selected in your jsFiddle is causing problems.

Add the following to external resources:

```
//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css
//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BNf74/)**

Resources: [jQuery UI Sortable page](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/)

Comment: This lead me to figure out that I that I had the script bundles included inside the body and not the head on my actual website.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the jQuery UI script

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F38xS/7/

Comment: well my example works after adding the script. My answer is correct. This looks like a jsfiddle problem to me.